# react.js antd carousel dots are not visible when slidesToShow={cards amount}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, antd

I have different number of cards in Carousel depends on screen resolutions.
And when I put in slidesToShow={cards amount} dots are not visible, they just disappear.
Currently my cards amount = 4

I try to add

```
 dots={true}
```

to Carousel but it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.